# Why Shiny is not rendering plotly graph after converting to modularized structure?

Tags: r, graph, shiny, module, r-plotly

Ok, after watching to Garrett's videos i'm totally in on converting my app functions to modules.
But I have no clue about what's going on with this APP. It was running perfectly before converting it to modules. The UI part is ok, the server part seems ok as well, since it is not crashing. It just doesn't show anything on the output in Tab1. What is going on?

#### callModules.R

```
# MODULE 1 UI
fotoModuleUI = function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    sliderInput(ns("fotoperiodo"), step = 0.1, post = ' horas de luz',
                    "Fotoperíodo para floração:",
                    min = 11.0,
                    max = 13.0,
                    value = 12),
    
    sliderInput(ns("latitude"), step = 0.01, post = ' degrees',
                    "Latitude:",
                    min = -50,
                    max = 50,
                    value = -23),
    
    selectInput(ns('choiceaxis'), 'Mostrar data por:',
                    choices = c('Data', 'Ciclo'), selected = 'Ciclo'),
    
    actionButton(ns('but1'), label = 'Processar'),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(3, 
             plotlyOutput('graph1.p', width = 'auto', height = 'auto')) #,
      # column(3, textOutput("info.graph1"))
      )
    )
  }
  
# MODULE 1 SERVER
fotoModule = function(input, output, session) {
  
  r.values = reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    req(input$but1) # must click
    ### calcFotoperiodo() is a outer function called with source() on the app.R
    mydata = calcFotoperiodo(isolate(input$latitude),outputForm = 'day',fotoperiodo = isolate(input$fotoperiodo))
    d.period = calcFotoperiodo(isolate(input$latitude),outputForm = 'period',fotoperiodo = isolate(input$fotoperiodo))
    
    r.values$mydata = mydata # a data frame
    r.values$d.period = d.period # a data frame
    
    xaxis = reactive(switch(
      input$choiceaxis,
      Data = as.Date(r.values$mydata$dias.ano), # vetor com dias do ano
      Ciclo = r.values$mydata$cum # vetor com dias do ciclo
    ))
    
    r.values$xaxis = xaxis()
    r.values$choiceaxis = input$choiceaxis
    r.values$latitude = input$latitude
    r.values$fotoperiodo = input$fotoperiodo
    r.values$floracao.I = if (input$choiceaxis == 'Data') r.values$d.period$Data.Floracao.I else r.values$d.period$Floracao.Ti
    r.values$floracao.F = if (input$choiceaxis == 'Data') r.values$d.period$Data.Floracao.F else r.values$d.period$Floracao.Tf
  })
  
  output$graph1.p = renderPlotly({
    req(input$but1)
    
    x = r.values$xaxis # vetor. vai ser uma data se input$choiceaxis = Data, ou o dia do ciclo se for = Ciclo
    y = r.values$mydata$duracao.dia
    
    dataplot = data.frame(x = x, y = y)
    
    range.xaxis = c(min(dataplot$x), max(dataplot$x) + 1)
    
    hoje = as.Date(today())
    today = if (input$choiceaxis == 'Data') hoje else r.values$mydata$cum[which(r.values$mydata$dias.ano == hoje)]
    
    plot_ly(dataplot) %>%
      add_lines(
        x = x,
        y = y,
        name = 'Variação do Fotoperíodo',
        color = I("brown")
      ) %>%
      add_lines(
        x = x,
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        color = I('grey'),
        type = 'a',
        name = 'Fotoperíodo de floração'
      ) %>%
      add_lines(
        x = x[r.values$mydata$vegetativo == T],
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        color = I('green'),
        type = 'a',
        name = 'Fase vegetativa'
      ) %>%
      add_lines(
        x = x[r.values$mydata$floracao == T],
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        color = I('purple'),
        type = 'a',
        name = 'Fase reprodutiva'
      ) %>%
      
      add_markers(
        x = r.values$floracao.I,
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        name = 'Início da Floração',
        color = I('red'),
        symbol = I('circle-dot'),
        size = 30
      ) %>%
      add_markers(
        x = r.values$floracao.F,
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        name = 'Fim da Floração',
        color = I('blue'),
        symbol = I('diamond'),
        size = 30
      ) %>%
      add_markers(
        x = today,
        y = r.values$fotoperiodo,
        name = 'Hoje',
        color = I('black'),
        symbol = I('cross'),
        size = 30
      ) %>%
      
      plotly::layout(
        xaxis = list(
          title = if (input$choiceaxis == 'Data')
            'Data'
          else
            "Dias do ciclo",
          range = range.xaxis
        ),
        yaxis = list(title = "Fotoperíodo", range = c(6, 18)),
        title = paste('Variação do Fotoperíodo na latitude ', input$latitude)
      ) %>%
      config(editable = F)
  })
}
```

#### App.R

```
# Load Modules ####
source('callModules.R')
source('calcFotoperiodo.R')

# UI####
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Title here'),
  fluid = T,collapsible = T,
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme('superhero'),
  tabsetPanel(
    id = 'tab1',
    ##### Tab 1 ####
    tabPanel(
      title = 'Análise de Fotoperíodo',
      fotoModuleUI('tab1'), # module output
      div(), hr(),
      tags$text('ADINC.'),
      tags$img(
        height = 30,
        width = 30,
        src = 'leaf.png',
        offset = 8)
    ), 
    ##### Tab 2 ####
      tabPanel(
        title = 'Análise Climática',
        fotoModuleUI('tab2') #module output
        )
    ),
  )

# SERVER ####

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Tab 1
  callModule(fotoModule, 'tab1')
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Session Info

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Comment: The inputId in your plotlyOutput is not namespaced. I think you need to wrap 'graph1.p' in the UI with a ns().

Comment: That's it! thank you , @bs93